# Constructing a Java method that returns a primitive data type that is decided by the input?

Tags: java

I would like a method to read a string, and return it's value in the implied (best fitting) data type. I would like to avoid doing the string to data type conversion in "main", as the code is likely to create clutter. Is this possible? Can I create a method that returns different types? What does the constructor look like?

Comment: What do you need to do with this value? If you end up doing type checks, you are back to having clutter even if the complex conversion itself has been hidden away.

Comment: This is a very bad idea as the only possible return type is `Object`, thus giving the caller responsibility for figuring out the type of the returned data.  This question is really not answerable without more context, specifically some examples of how you want to use this and evidence that you've thought about the implications of returning `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explore an enum type as a way to classify the type you end up with. You don't say what you want to use it for, so this may not be best, but it could be done in a way that handles the requirements you do give.

```
public class ClassifiedType
{
  public enum ClassifiedTypeType { INTEGER,  FLOAT,  STRING,  BOOLEAN };

  ClassifiedTypeType  typeType = null;
  int                 integerValue;
  float               floatValue;
  String              stringValue;
  boolean             booleanValue;

  public ClassifiedType(int i) { integerValue = i; typeType = ClassifiedTypeType.INTEGER; }
  public ClassifiedType(float f) { floatValue = f; typeType = ClassifiedTypeType.FLOAT; }
  // etc.

  public int getIntegerValue()
  {
    if (typeType != ClassifiedTypeType.INTEGER) 
    { 
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Attempting getInteger on type of " + this.toString());
    }
    else
    {
      return integerValue;
    }
  }

  // do gets for other types similarly.

  public static ClassifiedType getClassifiedType(String string)
  {
    // parse the string, determine which type you want, 
    // instantiate a ClassifiedType with its value and 
    // and type, and return it.
  }
}
```

Other classes can use the ClassifiedTypeType (hopefully with a better name) to determine what kind of value to get from it, to the extent they need that.

Anyway, it beats returning Object and then having to use `instanceof` all over the place to figure out what you're dealing with, and this extends to non-primitives if you ever need that.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to return different primitive types. What you can do is declare the method as returning `Object`, and at runtime return boxed primitives: instances of `Integer`, `Double`, `Boolean`, etc.

Comment: While this is definitely correct, I don't feel it fully answered the op's entire question

Comment: I don't have anything else to add unless the OP asks a follow up question.

Answer (score 1):

A single Java method **cannot** return multiple types. This is because Java is a strongly typed language.

There are a few different ways to accomplish this. If you'd like to go the constructor route as mentioned in the OP, it would look something like this:

```
public class Demo(){
    Demo(String str){
        // Do something...
    }

    Demo(int newInt){
        // Do something...
     }

    // Other constructors for other types here    
}
```

Comment: This would be my approach. Convenience methods such as `isString()`, `isInt()`, and `getAsString()`, `getAsInt()` and the like can reduce/hide away ugly type casting.

Comment: Yea I agree there are cleaner ways to do this, but OP seems to want to avoid manual checking of the data type in the code. You would need to do some manual conversion in order to use the correct helper methods. For the OP, I would like to point out that if you use the constructor method as shown above, type conversion is still happening behind the scenes. It may matter if your care is optimization.